Page NOT in the shared project does not show correctly in browser
I am trying to create a project in .net 9 and Blazor using the ".net Maui Blazor and Web App" template in Visual Studio.
I have created the project, and run it successfully, and I can see the project run as a Windows App, or set the Start Up project to the web project, and then run it in a browser.
So all good so far.
Now I add a test page to the Web Project called "Test".  I put it in the Web Project because I do NOT want it to be shared with the Maui project.  I then run the project again, and type in the address of the test page.  The "Test" page is displayed correctly for 1 second, and then disappears with a "not found" message.
If I add a test page to the Shared Directory, it displays normally.
I have been unable to resolve this.  I have created a Test Repo here:  https://github.com/gregoryagu/MauiApp5
What do I need to do to get the Test page to display normally?

First, why it doesn't work. The chain here is:

In Web/Program.cs the root is app.MapRazorComponents<App>()

Web/Components.App.razor uses <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

Shared/Routes.razor has <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Layout.MainLayout).Assembly" >


So the router scans for pages in the assembly that contains MainLayout. What you would need (but doesn't immediately work) is
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Layout.MainLayout).Assembly" 
      AdditionalAssemblies="typeof(Pages.Test)">    

Since you can't have a circular dependency from Shared back to the Web assembly you will need a separate Router. I'm not sure if there are any disadvantages to this, but be ware.

copy Routes.razor to Web/Components. Rename it to RoutesWeb.razor .
Add AdditionalAssemblies="[typeof(Pages.Test).Assembly]" to the first line.
Also add Shared to DefaultLayout="typeof(Shared.Layout.MainLayout)"
In App.razor , change the Routes element to <RoutesWeb @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />


This works great.  I have checked in the changes to the repo in case anyone else runs into the same issue. I always learn something good from Henk!
